# Сортировка массива составленного из JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Собственно есть код JSON:

```
    "1": {
            "username": "Игрок",
            "balance": 228,
        }
```

Таких ячеек много и они все с разными номерами, которые в свою очередь никак не связанны между собой.

Дальше я иду таким путём:

```js
  var top = [];
  var fs = require('fs');
  var contents = fs.readFileSync("./accounts.json", 'utf8');
  template = JSON.parse(contents);
  const arr = Object.keys(template);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      top[top.length] = {
      "balance": template[arr[i]].balance,
      "name": template[arr[i]].username
    }
  }
```

И нужно как-то массив `top` отсортировать по `balance` в каждой ячейке массива.

**Примерно должно получиться так:**

Было:

```
    [
    "1": {
                "username": "Игрок",
                "balance": 228,
            },
    "123": {
                "username": "Игрок",
                "balance": 0,
            }
    ]
```

Стало:

```
    [
    "123": {
                "username": "Игрок",
                "balance": 0,
            },
    "1": {
                "username": "Игрок",
                "balance": 228,
            }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var contents = `{
  "1": {
    "username": "Игрок",
    "balance": 228
  }, 
  "2": {
    "username": "Игрок",
    "balance": 5
  }, 
  "3": {
    "username": "Игрок",
    "balance": 1457
  }
}`;

var tops = [];
var template = JSON.parse(contents);
var arr = Object.keys(template);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  tops[tops.length] = {
    "balance": template[arr[i]].balance,
    "name": template[arr[i]].username
  }
}

var res = tops.sort(function(a, b){
  return +a.balance - +b.balance;
});
console.log(res);
```